# Ruby OOP terminology: How do you call "devise" and ":trackable" in this class?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Here is a Ruby ActiveRecord class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_tokens
  devise :trackable, :confirmable
```

I have two Ruby terminology questions about it:

1. How do you call `:confirmable`, is it an "aspect" of class User?
2. In the code above, how do you call the `devise` word? Is it a "method call"?

*PS: I am quite new to Ruby. I have searched online, and read many Ruby OOP tutorials, but none gave those two things a proper name.*

Comment: It's not a standard Ruby class, it's an ActiveRecord class.

Comment: @Doud: Thanks, edited. The fact that it is ActiveRecord is not very important for the question, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`devise` is a method call, it could be either a class or instance method, I'm not sure.  I think here it is best to refer to `:confirmable` as an argument which is passed to the `devise` method.  You'd best refer to the devise docs for a better understanding of what its role is.

Comment: `devise is a class method. You can tell because it's being called in the class context (and will be called upon an instance's initialization) rather than inside an instance method.

Comment: When you have method calls in the body of a class like `devise` or `has_many` or `validates`, they are referred to as "class macros". You don't see everyone use this, but I think it makes an appearance in the Pickaxe book, and I'm pretty sure it's in Metaprogramming Ruby (*really* good book, btw).

Comment: @Jordan While `devise` appears to *call* a class method, in the provided context the word "devise" is being used to call a method, so I think calling it a "method call" is valid (in Ruby terms).

Comment: I agree, @coreyward; I didn't mean to imply that the answer was incorrect, only to provide clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Devise is a class method, correct. Confirmable is either a method, or an attribute, or both-not sure how devise implements it.

Comment: It's a method. Attribute readers accept no arguments and attribute writers accept only one.